# How to run a file's custom system verb that contains spaces

Tags: autohotkey

When using the following script:

Run, *verb TargetFile

...Is there any way to make it work for verbs that contain a space? Simply writing it out as normal, the program interprets anything after the space as part of the target file. I've tried passing the verb as a variable, using double quotes in various spaces, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you said you had tried double quotes, here is an example that works with run and contains spaces:

Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com

The most common use for a space in ahk is %A_Space%.

You could also try backtick s ('s btw I can't use backticks here, but they are below the ~ on a US keyboard). The use of 's is rare but has been shown to work in [concatenation](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/92889-have-s-represent-a-space-character/).